# How to Use Macro in Laravel Http::Pool?

Tags: laravel, http, asynchronous, pool

I want to add a macro to Http::loop to define base url. I am using Laravel 9, so far I followed these steps:

1 - Add Macro to app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Http::macro('adequateshop', function () {
            return Http::baseUrl('http://restapi.adequateshop.com');
        });
}
```

2 - Trying to access the macro using Http::loop

```php
        $responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
            $pool->adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=1'),
            $pool->adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=2'),
            $pool->adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=3'),
            $pool->adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=4'),
        ]);
```

I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::adequateshop does not exist.
```

I tried to access the macro (without Http::loop) and it worked:

```php
$response = Http::adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=1');
```

**Question 1: Does anyone knows if it is possible to access macros under Http::loop()**

**Question 2:
Can I have multiple macros like this:**

```
$responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
            $pool->adequateshop()->get('/api/Tourist?page=1'),
            $pool->github()->get('/api/endpoint'),
            $pool->google()->get('/api/endpoint'),
            $pool->stackoverflow()->get('/api/endpoint'),
        ]);
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: `Pool` is a different class than what `Http` is a proxy for (Factory), so the macro is on a different class ... though `PendingRequest` is macroable, so that is what you would have to add the macro on if you want to make those calls on a `Pool` instance (which would call that on `PendingRequest`

Comment: @lagbox Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @lagbox, for your suggestion. This code is working:

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        PendingRequest::macro('adequateshop', function () {
            return PendingRequest::baseUrl('http://restapi.adequateshop.com');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I had the error `Error: Call to a member function wait() on null` until I saw your answer and replaced my macro code with `PendingRequest::asJson` instead of `Http::asJson`.